# System.OutOfMemoryException error occur when filling DataTable in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have large record like more then 1 000 000 and I want to fill this data into DataTable, but at time of filling DataTable it is throwing exception like `System.OutOfMemoryException`. How I can solve this error?
Also I have 4 GB RAM and 64-bit operating system.

Comment: Did you mean that to be 10 million records, or 1 million? (Having two 0s at the end is unusual.) Do you really *have* to have the whole thing in memory? There are ways to make this more efficient so you can get more into memory at a time, but 10 million records is quite a lot to have in memory in one go... (Even if all 4GB can go towards that, that's only 429 bytes per record, which really isn't a lot.)

Comment: What is Iac? Soerry - just ran into a `OutOfVocabulary` exception

Comment: So 1 million? Please bear in mind that "lac" isn't a commonly used term for many readers. I'll edit your question to represent 1 million in the more common way. But even so, do you definitely need all those records in memory at once?

Comment: @Serv: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh - basically it's 100,000.

Comment: sorry that was typing mistake

Comment: *Why* do you need more than a million rows in memory at once?

Comment: how about some paged query?

Comment: @JonSkeet > thanks ! I've learnt something interesting today, even if it has nothing to do with programming ! Shree, I'm agree with others, you should better avoid to load so much data at once. Please also keep in mind that you don't need to really overflow your physical memory to get OOM exception : think about LOH fragmentation and issues like this...

Answer (score 6):

If you -need- all that data in memory, and your app pool is x64, and you are using .NET 4.5, you can use the `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` directive... to do this for ASP.NET, you'd need to add your own `aspnet.config` file for your app pool (see [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/setting-an-aspnet-config-file-per-application-pool) for more info) and set this configuration for startup:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

That said, handling such a large `DataTable` in memory all at once is more likely not the way to go, specially for web applications (which will generally work for more than one user).

Having that much memory occupied (per user, probably), while you more likely only work on a small subset of that memory at any given time, is just a waste, and you should probably be looking at a different way of handling the problem, rather than bruteforcing .NET to allow for larger objects in memory.

Comment: Thanks Jcl. But I used this ever before, still showing error. Any other then this.

Comment: Well, if those 1 million records are large and you have only 4gb of RAM (not for the process, but for the whole system), you might consider that you actually **do not have enough memory** on your system for it, and if that's the case, the only way would be adding more memory. This is rather unpractical, and you may want to think twice about the handling of that data, instead of loading it all in memory at once.

Comment: Even if you load 1M records, you will still need to "iterate" through them in some way. The approach of loading everything is usually wrong, and your real problem is how to perform your processing with reasonable performance and smaller memory footprint on a large data set. Now, for the 10th time, what are you doing with the data and why do you need all the records loaded at once?

Comment: Is there any other way to specify the size of temporary memory in web.config file?

Comment: Try to compile application for x64 (instead of Any CPU) and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Also, the `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` directive would only work upon initialization (in the app pool), not on `web.config`