# converting datatable to xml giving outofmemory exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datatable, stringwriter

While trying to converting a datatable data to xml through stringwriter. It si giving outof memory exception.

My datatable contains about 20000 records.

Below is the code I am trying

```
DataTable dt = GetData();// contains 20000 records.

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    dt.WriteXml(sw);

    XmlDocument sd = new XmlDocument();
    sd.LoadXml(sw.ToString());
```

Can someone help me please.

Comment: Which line is running out of memory? Writing the xml or loading?

Comment: sd.LoadXml(sw.ToString());  This line giving error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.OutOfMemoryException error occour when filling DataTable in asp.net using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249598/system-outofmemoryexception-error-occour-when-filling-datatable-in-asp-net-using)

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do to reduce memory use is to eliminate the intermediate `StringBuilder` and `string` representations and write directly from the `DataTable` to the `XmlDocument` by passing the `XmlWriter` returned from  [`XmlDocument.CreateNavigator.AppendChild()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163341.aspx) into [`DataTable.WriteXml(XmlWriter)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.writexml):

```
var sd = new XmlDocument();
using (var writer = sd.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
{
    dt.WriteXml(writer);
}
```

This should also be more performant as it is no longer necessary to parse the intermediate XML string.

(Similarly, a `DataSet` can be written directly to an `XmlDocument` using [`DataSet.WriteXml(writer)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.writexml).)

---

Here is the test code I used to verify this approach on an x86 process:

```
class TestClass
{
    internal static void Test()
    {
        // Verify the old and new algorithms generate identical XML
        foreach (var i in new[] { 0, 1, 2, 100 })
        {
            var old1 = TestStringWriteAndParse(i);
            var new1 = TestDirectWrite(i);

            if (old1.OuterXml != new1.OuterXml)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("old1.OuterXml != new1.OuterXml");
            }
        }

        // Find a number of records that generate an out-of-memory exception whcn converting to an intermediate StringBuilder and string:
        uint size = 20000;
        try
        {
            while (size < int.MaxValue / 2)
            {
                TestStringWriteAndParse((int)size);
                size = checked(size * 2);
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        GC.Collect();

        // Verify that number of records can be written directly using  XmlDocument.CreateNavigator.AppendChild()

        try
        {
            TestDirectWrite((int)size);
            Console.WriteLine("SUCCEEDED in writing {0} DataTable records to an XmlDocument", size);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FAILED in writing {0} DataTable records to an XmlDocument:", size);
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    static DataTable GetData(int count)
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.TableName = "Test";

        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Height", typeof(double));
        table.Columns.Add("NetWorth", typeof(decimal));

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = "Bob Cratchit " + i.ToString();
            row["Height"] = 6.023;
            row["NetWorth"] = 101.01 + (10 * i);
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }

    static XmlDocument TestDirectWrite(int count)
    {
        DataTable dt = GetData(count);// contains 20000 records.

        XmlDocument sd = new XmlDocument();
        using (XmlWriter writer = sd.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
        {
            dt.WriteXml(writer);
        }

        return sd;
    }

    static XmlDocument TestStringWriteAndParse(int count)
    {
        DataTable dt = GetData(count);// contains 20000 records.

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        dt.WriteXml(sw);

        XmlDocument sd = new XmlDocument();
        sd.LoadXml(sw.ToString());

        return sd;
    }
}
```

In my case the original code failed trying to serialize 1280000 records while the new code succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a file stream instead of string writer.

```
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(path);
XMLDocument doc = new XMLDocuemnt();
doc.Load(stream);
```

Comment: What is this path I should provide??